# Private setter does not prevent changing an array element

Tags: c#, setter

In my code, in main window class, I have an array:

```
public TextBox[,] Letterbox { get; private set; } = new TextBox[4, 4];
```

and in other class, I try doing

```
my_main_window.Letterbox[1, 1] = null;
```

and it works just fine. I want the array to be accessible to read, but not write, to other classes. How should I do it?

Comment: In your case `private set` means that you cannot set another instance of `TextBox[,]` into `Letterbox` property but can set his element.
So I suggest you to use a some `ReadOnlyCollection`.

Answer (score 3):

Answer: Letterbox, as a property, is an array property. The code rightly prevents you from setting a new value.... for the array.

However, anything with access to that array may do whatever they wish with the array.

To do what you are intending to do, you will need an [indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/indexers/).

```
public class LetterBox
{
    private TextBox[,] array = new TextBox[4, 4];
    public TextBox this[int x, int y]
    {
        get
        {
            return array[x, y];
        }
    }
}
```

(You'll still need some way of setting it, but this is how you make the construct you are looking for.)